# Assigning boolean to number with || operator - strange behaviour

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typing

According to typescript type system,  cannot be assigned to .

However, having some background with Javascript, I've tried the next batch of code and the result is rather unclear for me:

```
let booleanVariable: boolean = false;
let numberVariable: number = booleanVariable || 1;
// compiles just fine > numberVariable = 1
```

If I'm to change '|| 1' to '|| 0', then the compiler error occurs:

```
let booleanVariable: boolean = false;
let numberVariable: number = 0 || booleanVariable;
// type false is not assignable to number
```

If I'm to change 'booleanVariable' to 'true', compiler error arises:

```
let booleanVariable: boolean = true;
let numberVariable: number = booleanVariable|| 1;
// type true is not assignable to type number
```

And there could be even more adjustment with changing true to false and replacing the order of operands with '||' operator. If someone could explain such behaviour based on aforementioned examples, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line, the type of `booleanVariable` is not `boolean` but `false`.

```
let booleanVariable: boolean = false;
```

It seems you can't see the real type by hovering the variable in the playground or your IDE. But if you need to be convinced, you could do:

```
const booleanVariable: boolean = false ;
const tmp = booleanVariable; // Here the type of `tmp` is inferred as `false`
```

Here is how to declare `booleanVariable` as a real `boolean`:

```
let booleanVariable = false as boolean;
```

Now, the next instruction is an error:

```
let numberVariable: number = booleanVariable || 1; // Error: Type 'true | 1' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

In JavaScript `0` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), then the expression `0 || booleanVariable` always returns `booleanVariable`. So, TypeScript infers that the type of the expression is the type of `booleanVariable`:

```
let numberVariable: number = 0 || booleanVariable; // Error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought that 'false|true' is just the representatives of type 'boolean', and so if I'm to declare something as 'boolean' with a value of 'false|true', expression containing this declaration will behave just like you showed with 'as boolean'.